# Regarding the specifity of the A.M.-G.M. inequality in finding maximum and minimum in Number Theory

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Today, my math teacher solved a problem which asked to find the **maximum value** of the expression $x^2y^3$ when $x$ and $y$ are related as $3x+4y=5$.

It was solved using the classic A.M.-G.M. inequality by splitting $3x$ as twice of $3x/2$ and $4y$ as thrice of $4y/3$.

He finally got an inequality as $x^2y^3\le3/16$ and he directly mapped the maximum value of the expression to 3/16 by solely depending only on this inequality. I don't get this point of assigning its maximum value. What if some other inequality says that it is even lesser than 3/16 or restricts its range even further to numbers which are less than 3/16. Can't we give any **counterexample inequalities**? Or won't any such inequality ever exist? If yes, then why?

I'm a pre-calculus student and I'm still a beginner and am sorry if my question is too dishonorable.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Using the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AM%E2%80%93GM_inequality) requires that $x$ and $y$ both be non-negative. Although you didn't explicitly specify this, I assume that's a stated condition.

Comment: Few observations: 1. The proof is valid only when $x,y$ are positive. 2. Assuming this is the case, if we can show that the equality case (i.e., 3/16) is possible for some value of $(x,y)$, then we can _know_ for sure that it is the maximum. Take $x = 2/3, y = 3/4$

Comment: AM-GM is tight if and only if all the participating positive numbers are equal. It is surely possible that $3x/2=4y/3$ (in addition to $3x+4y=5$). Most likely you want to check that :-)

Comment: Yes of course these are positive.

Answer (score 0):

The AM-GM inequality says that for non-negative reals $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k$ we always have $$\frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_k}{k}\geq \sqrt[k]{x_1x_2\cdots x_k},$$
with equality if and only if $x_1=x_2=\cdots=x_k$.

Here the result says we have equality if and only if $3x/2=4y/3$. Since this can happen (if $x=2/3$ and $y=3/4$), the upper bound we get is actually the maximum.

Comment: So we accept this as our maximum because it is in accordance with our given linear relation?

Comment: @BlackKnight23 we accept it as the maximum because we've found some values that attain it (and we've proved nothing does better).

Answer (score 0):

If you can prove $x^2y^3 \leqslant 3/16$ [which AM-GM does with the restriction to positive numbers] AND show that equality can be achieved for some value [as it does in this case for $(x_0, y_0) = (\frac23, \frac34)$]; then we can conclude $3/16$ is the maximum.

In general if you can show $f(x, y,...) \leqslant C=f(x_0, y_0, ...)$ for some fixed real $C$ and allowable $(x_0, y_0,...)$, then you have the global maximum as $C$.  (Similarly for the minimum, with the sign reversed.).

Note both conditions are required, and together they practically define what a global maximum (or minimum) is.

Comment: Actually your explanation seems too complicated for me to grasp but I'm able to say that the statement which says that global maximum is achieved when the inequality changes into an equality forms the basis of my how. So it would be nice if I had some further explanation.

Comment: Glad to explain further if you can detail what portion / sentence you find complicated.  In essence though what you said is right, if the inequality can become an equality, we have found the maximum.  Otherwise the inequality may still be correct, but it just gives an upper bound. For e.g. here quite obviously we can say $x \le 5/3, y \le 5/4$ to satisfy the linear constraint and positivity, so $x^2y^3 \le 5^5/(3^2\cdot 4^3)$ is a valid inequality, however you wont find an allowable value of $x, y$ which can make it an equality, hence it is not the maximum, though it remains an upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

AM-GM tells us that $x^2y^3 \le \frac{3}{16}$. It also has an equality case, when all of the terms in the AM-GM are equal—in your case, that would be when $\frac{3x}{2} = \frac{4y}{3}$. Combining this with the assumption $3x + 4y = 5$, this gives us only one pair where equality holds: $(x, y) = (\tfrac{2}{3},\tfrac{3}{4})$.

So, if I understand your question correctly, you’re asking why we can outright say that $\frac{3}{16}$ is the maximum. After all, some stronger inequality might be able to prove that $x^2y^3$ is always less than a value less than $\frac{3}{16}$.

The word ‘maximum’ essentially consists of two parts. So, when your teacher is saying that $x^2y^3$ has a maximum value of $\frac{3}{16}$, he/she is saying two things:

1. $x^2y^3 \le \frac{3}{16}$ for all positive reals $x$ and $y$ such that $3x + 4y = 5$.
2. There exists a pair $(x, y)$ that satisfies $3x + 4y = 5$ such that $x^2y^3 = \frac{3}{16}$.

The second condition is equivalent to saying that the bound of $\frac{3}{16}$ can’t be reduced any further.

So, in our case, are both conditions met? By AM-GM, the first condition is met, as you noted. The second condition is also met because we have found values of $x$ and $y$, namely $\frac{2}{3}$ and $\frac{3}{4}$, where equality is met, as $(\frac{2}{3})^2(\frac{3}{4})^3 = \frac{3}{16}$.

I hope this made sense.